# Android JavaScript in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have tried to create a webview with JavaScript, but I get the error:

'Cannot cast View from WebView' on the line `WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);`

This is the full code

```
package com.CalvaryChapelMelbourne.CCM;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class WebView extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    public WebView() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

}
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainWebView"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your slightly confused. See below for correct Activity implementation:

```
package com.CalvaryChapelMelbourne.CCM;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

}
```

or if you wanted to construct a WebView object:

```
public WebView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainWebView, null); // The xml file name not the id
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new in Android development, **We DONT DEFINE A CONSTRUCTOR OF ACTIVITY , you should override the method** `onCreate(Bundle icircle);` like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icircle) {
        super(icircle);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

}
```

**NOTE :  Dont rename your activities with names of UIElements or Classes like WebView , TextView ...etc**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define a class WebView as a subclass of Activity
but WebView is already a subclass of View ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html )

The method **findViewById(..)** of Activity will return a View which you cannot cast
to an Activity.

You have to rename your class (is that class the class you launch at the beginning?)

Try like this:

```
public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

You also have to adjust your AndroidManifest.xml.